# Symfony2 FormType Entity set value to specific property

Tags: forms, symfony, types

I'm generating a form and have an entity mapped to a select field, using the entity FormType

I can set the select to display whatever property i like with:

`'property' => 'myProperty'` (in symfony 2.7 its) `'choice_label' => 'myProperty'`

I'm Using Symfony 2.6 so the `'choice_value'` option is not avaliable

I don't see a way to specify which property to use as the actual value of the select, it seems to default to the id field, which isn't what i want.

```
$myData = $this->fpem->getRepository('GameBundle:ContestTimeKey')->getCurrentKeysQuery($currentTimeframe);
    $builder
        ->add('contestTimeKey', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'GameBundle:ContestTimeKey',
            'property' => 'dateString',
            'query_builder' => $myData,
            'label' => 'Select Date',
            'placeholder' => 'Pick a Date',
        ))
        ->add('userID', 'hidden')
        ->getForm();
}
```

The `$myData` is a query returned from the repository getting the entities i want to populate the select with.

Comment: You can try with another property - `choice_value`. A callback function that receives entity item as an argument and from there you can return `$entity->yourProperty();` for instance. Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization)

Comment: You can use **Data Transformers**
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: Or you could just set the `data` attribute with the desired value and solve the problem? I.e. `array('data' => 5)` will select `£5` from your `entryFee` choices (the same applies if it's an entity, you would instead pass your desired entity as `data` instead of `5`). [Official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data)

Comment: @Officialdocumentation setting `data` is very invonvenient and should be avoided for dynamic lists AFAIK

Comment: Thanks for the replies, its the first item of the form ContestTimeKey.

The Data is returned from the ContestTimeKeyRepository
I have 3 properties ID, Date and DateString.

I want dateString to be displayed on the select (which it is) and the value to be set to the date property.